# Index row formula error on Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a formula in Google spreadsheet from cell B2 all teh way to B100 which is

B2=iferror(INDEX(DB!$B:$AC,SMALL(IF(DB!$B:$AC=$A$1,ROW(DB!$B:$AC)),ROW(1:1)),0), "")
B3=iferror(INDEX(DB!$B:$AC,SMALL(IF(DB!$B:$AC=$A$1,ROW(DB!$B:$AC)),ROW(2:2)),0), "")
B4=iferror(INDEX(DB!$B:$AC,SMALL(IF(DB!$B:$AC=$A$1,ROW(DB!$B:$AC)),ROW(3:3)),0), "")
B5=iferror(INDEX(DB!$B:$AC,SMALL(IF(DB!$B:$AC=$A$1,ROW(DB!$B:$AC)),ROW(4:4)),0), "")
..
...
......

So it is pulling up values from a second tab which is named as "DB".

The Index row formula looks for the status  "Completed" ( which is on cell  A1) and return the details for all completed from the DB.

Google spreadsheet 
[main spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2zm9.jpg)

Database in tab 2 (DB) 
[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeHpt.jpg)

The formula works fine , however i am getting duplicates of every cell which got the status "Completed "

Attached links to the screen shots for your reference. 
Don't know what i am missing. 0_o
Thanks

Comment: what exactly are  you trying to pull from **DB**? what is the relation between your formula and the duplicates? explain more please. I tried to create the same sheets in my own excel and simulate the problem, but I don't know what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, 
There are rows in the db with status "Completed " , " in Queue" , "resolving issues" , " in progress"  and some are blank. 

With this formula on tab1  it will only get details for rows for "completed"  from the db . 

And A1 tab is where we enter the satus what we like to pull from db , so for example: If I enter A1 in tab one as "RESOLVING ISSUES" It will come back with row which have teh status "RESOLVING ISSUES"

Comment: Regarding duplicates : - the formula is returning the result twice for each row, which should not happen. :-|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use QUERY() for what you try to achieve.
Have a look at [this example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iYMZ_3l4SCvFzL7RoJvS5f_3RxgDtWV6E86oNr1Kh3s/edit?usp=sharing) and check sheet 2 where this formula is used to filter the data from sheet 1:

```
=query(Sheet1!A:H, "select * where B = '"&A1&"' ")
```

(where A1 is a drop down list with the values 'COMPLETED', 'in progress', 'resolving').
See if that helps ?

Comment: Wow, that worked flawlessly . Thank you very much. Much appreciated  :)

Answer (score 0):

there is no need for formula here. 


This is simply done by filtering:

Supposing you have a DB sheet [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBfv5.png)
In your [main sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbHcI.png), put DB!A1 in cell A1, and drag and fill horizontally and vertically, to **copy** exactly your **DB** sheet into *main* sheet (you can do this selectively as well, there is no need to copy every column, just cpy those you want). Then click on **FILTER**, you can find it in ***SORT AND FILTER***, then you will see a dropdown menu on all of the column headers. Simply by clicking on your **status** header, you can selected **completed** and press OK, it will ONLY show rows with completed on their status column.

And [here is the link to download this example sheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f25iaow4gwr537k/filter.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Hi, the db is used by 20 different people who update 50 -60 rows every day and changing status. Filtering another 10 staff while they making changes is not ideal , thats why we came up with this on a different tab. Which works very well except for duplicates. 
but thanks for your support. :)

Comment: i still dont get the point. In my answer, you don't filter in DB, you do your filtering in a new tab. In this new tab, you can copy all of your DB sheet to new tab using a simple formula like =DB!A1 for cell A1 in main sheet. and each time DB gets updated, your new sheet gets updates as well, and your filtering still will work.

Comment: Tried yesterday this works,but my db got above 6000 cells, other guys who works here is not confident in excel as i am, they want something very simple.
But very useful information, something i didn't know. :) Thank you

Comment: you're welcome, so if my answer tried to bring a solution to your question, then please accept it as the answer to your question so that future users in stackoverflow will know directly what to read.

Answer (score 0):

your links don't work for me.

You should use the [FILTER() function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197), that is designed exactly for this purpose:

in cell A2 on your second sheet use: `=filter('DB'!B:AC,'DB'!B:B=$A$1)`

As suggested I would use Data validation with dropdown list, so that only valid statuses may be chosen.